# Lightning: Are there any global variables to check current user profile or custom permissions?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, global-variables

Currently, only $Browser and $Locale are available as global value providers.

Are there any ideas how to check profile and custom permissions of current user without running SOQL query in @auraenabled apex? I had a look into $A.* but no available helper javascript functions that seems can verify profile details.

Comment: What would be your use case for this?

Comment: For example, there are two tabs on the page: View and Create. Create tab should be shown for users, who have Create custom permission. Or permission to see exclusive data(like we can use {!$Permission.canSeeExecutiveData} on VF page )

Comment: Well, you can query that with a call to an auraenabled apex method, or I guess this is a feature request to have built in js methods that make this call, but in both cases the data is on the server, not on the client. In the situation of visualforce, it also runs on the server so the data is right there and the VF permission call is possible.

Comment: The only way to make it available on the client would be to serialize down all the permissions on page load. Prohibitively expensive, so you'll need to do what Robert Sussland suggested.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, the more value providers that are added, the more weight we add to every request. Serializing down all the permissions would be crazy expensive as well.

You'll need to provide that information to your component from the server yourself, sorry.